# How to start to recovery mode in a Mac OS X VM in Parallels?

Tags: macos, startup, virtualization, parallels-desktop, recovery

Is it possible to start into Recovery/Internet recovery mode in a virtualized Mac OS X in Parallels?

It would come in handy to take screenshots of those UIs or running apps to exemplify some steps especially here at askdifferent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've found a way:

1. Enable `Select boot device at startup` in the virtual machine

[image]

2. After the startup of the VM press any key to enter the boot device menu

[image]

3. Select `Boot Maintenance Manager`

[image]

4. Select `Boot from file`

[image]

5. Search your recovery volume (usually it's the 2nd one listed)

[image]

6. Select `com.apple.recovery.boot`

[image]

7. Select `boot efi`

[image]

8. Recovery mode:

[image]

In Yosemite the mouse acts flaky though and i can't hoover the mouse over the menubar (e.g. to start /Utilities/Terminal) - it immediately jumps to the framing window. Menu navigation with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to circumvent this malfunction doesn't work.

In Mavericks everything seems to work bug-free.

**Addendum: You may access the menubar with your pointer after enabling FileVault 2 on the VM's system drive. **

Comment: Works the same way with VirtualBox, you just have to press F2 when booting the UEFI to get into the setup (instead of going into settings).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to enter the EFI shell, but on catalina the path is different (at least on my image!). 
By using the menu instead of the shell, I was able to read the device label (RECOVERY), which pointed me in the right direction.
The `boot.efi` was in a UUID like folder. ty